# in partial view, javascript function runs exponentially

Tags: javascript, function, view, partial

Partial View loaded into div using ajax

On document ready, a javascript function is called.

1st time view opened abc() called once.
2nd time view, opened abc() called twice.
3rd time view opened, abc() called 3 times.

Seems cache is not cleared